# Join multiple columns from 2 tables in a SQL database

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is on a Postgres server using SQL. I have a `supply_chain` table in which I need to pull the `warehouse_id` from, and an `order` table in which I need to pull the total returns. Located on the same server.

I need to combine them on the delivery zipcode from the order table and the zipcode on the supply_chain table. I am unsure the best way to join this in SQL.

```
SELECT deliveryzipcode, COUNT(OrderReturned) AS Total_returned
FROM transactions_log
WHERE OrderReturned= 'Yes'
GROUP BY deliveryzipcode;
```

This query will successfully return the number of returns based on zipcode. So basically I need to pull those `warehouse_id`'s and count them.

[image]

Apologize in advance for not wording this question well.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Is this really about two different databases or rather about two tables in one database? If the latter, show some sample data for the two tables and the result you are expecting.

Comment: And what DBMS are you using? SQL requests should always be tagged with the DBMS in question in order to get working answers.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the tag for type if SQL (SQL server, Oracle etc.), then please edit your question and clarify where the tables are - same database? same server? different server?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
SELECT sc.warehouse_id, sc.zipcode, tl.Total_returned
FROM logistics_supply_chain_network AS sc
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT deliveryzipcode, COUNT(OrderReturned) AS Total_returned
    FROM transactions_log
   WHERE OrderReturned= 'Yes'
   GROUP BY deliveryzipcode
) AS tl
ON tl.deliveryzipcode = sc.zipcode ;
```